OpenSSH locally verify passphrase and security key
I'm running in cmd (as admin) ssh-keygen -t ed25519-sk -C "comment" to generate an SSH keypair. I successfully enter a passphrase and tap my security key when prompted.
Program/device info:
OpenSSH_for_Windows_9.5p1, LibreSSL 3.8.2
Yubikey Firmware: 5.4.3 FIDO2
I've then tried verifying the passphrase and security key work with these commands:

ssh-keygen -yP "" -f id_ed25519_sk error: incorrect passphrasessh-keygen -yP "passphrase" -f id_ed25519_sk output: public key
neither command asks for security key

ssh-keygen -yef id_ed25519_sk output: public key
doesn't ask me for passphrase or security key


This leads me being quite confused on how this private key works.

Is the private key file not encrypted by the passphrase, given -e allows it to be used without?
Same question for the security key - public key can be retrieved without it?

Or is there something wrong with how my machine is generating the keypair
I'm curious to know what exactly the passphrase and security key options are supposed to do to my private key

As requested, test keys generated with ssh-keygen -t ed25519-sk -C "TEST_ONLY", using the passphrase pass & security key
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
b3BlbnNzaC1rZXktdjEAAAAACmFlczI1Ni1jdHIAAAAGYmNyeXB0AAAAGAAAABCBRnBaW6
YLk99nRUcnaDafAAAAGAAAAAEAAABKAAAAGnNrLXNzaC1lZDI1NTE5QG9wZW5zc2guY29t
AAAAIJw48q5Bq2428WPN4TJtR/C8z8gPnUGpCSyWOcDWuTsHAAAABHNzaDoAAADwFVomEb
8iNzd/1snoVliJ1SVqP69AwchgLDrzh5j3C+5FWwKKeqElJxJVdWCQBpy3dm9pyEMfkAy/
yq2M/oEua1eQ5LiHdcjEh1JjZDWra1jXAHxi+WwryRw0H6wrvLwp4kt9NxgZjMelf3YMsL
5OnLcnm97QP/nOD3caKkMO4RjmQHTJXXbQBJkj0zVsTqEEh5af4kkOA0op/nodOZaQRXvH
Dwf8J2A/DeWrZoeYj9KSYgqyAWwfby7jwF+hkWzQNZfAlT6LNunlUxxJXe9zCat6QvjV22
GCtpsRi8EooJDBdWXCjvhEvQO53khAdEzf
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----

sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com AAAAGnNrLXNzaC1lZDI1NTE5QG9wZW5zc2guY29tAAAAIJw48q5Bq2428WPN4TJtR/C8z8gPnUGpCSyWOcDWuTsHAAAABHNzaDo= TEST_ONLY

As before, outputs are
C:\Users\Shuri2060\.ssh>ssh-keygen -yP "" -f TEST_id_ed25519_sk
Load key "TEST_id_ed25519_sk": incorrect passphrase supplied to decrypt private key

C:\Users\Shuri2060\.ssh>ssh-keygen -yP "pass" -f TEST_id_ed25519_sk
sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com AAAAGnNrLXNzaC1lZDI1NTE5QG9wZW5zc2guY29tAAAAIJw48q5Bq2428WPN4TJtR/C8z8gPnUGpCSyWOcDWuTsHAAAABHNzaDo= TEST_ONLY

C:\Users\Shuri2060\.ssh>ssh-keygen -yef TEST_id_ed25519_sk
---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
Comment: "256-bit ED25519-SK, converted by shuri2060@Shuri2060-PC from"
AAAAGnNrLXNzaC1lZDI1NTE5QG9wZW5zc2guY29tAAAAIJw48q5Bq2428WPN4TJtR/C8z8
gPnUGpCSyWOcDWuTsHAAAABHNzaDo=
---- END SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----


Can you create a test key, one you don’t intend to use, and run the same command. I suspect this is a format problem, as I remember numerous questions, by users with the exact same error which were all caused by the file format. We will need the contents of these tests keys, as text and perhaps a screenshot, to make sure we capture any formatting the file has.

@Ramhound Thanks, I have edited at the bottom. Could you link any such questions if you remember, so I can try researching as well? I asked this question after failing to find anything on it

The OpenSSH 'new' format privatekey file contains

some metadata (about the encryption)

an always-unencrypted part that contains the public key

a usually-encrypted part that contains the private key info and the comment (although if you enter an empty passphrase this part is left unencrypted)


The OpenSSH publickey file format -- used in known_hosts and authorized_keys and similar -- that -y must produce contains the public key and the comment; the public key is always readable, but if a passphrase is used that passphrase is needed to decrypt the last part to get the comment. I'm not really sure why they did this; the old format consisted of the public key and comment unencrypted in id_xxx.pub and the private key in usually-encrypted OpenSSL format in id_xxx; in that case you didn't need -y at all because .pub already existed. It conceivably might be intended to bind the comment to the key, but I don't see how there was/is an attack without, plus unauthenticated CTR mode encryption is malleable anyway (and the position of the comment trivial to determine).
In contrast -e (note you don't need -ye; specifying both only executes the -e and ignores the -y) creates the 'standard' (but really Tectia) format with a dummy comment, not the real one. Thus it doesn't need the passphrase to decrypt the last part of the file.
(For completeness -e -m pem for RSA only, and -e -m pkcs8 which is really SPKI and not PKCS8 at all, generate formats containing only the public key and no comment either real or fake, so they don't need passphrase.)
Neither of these operations actually uses the private key (-y decrypts it but ignores it).
For a key based in a hardware device such as Yubikey, the OpenSSH file continues to contain the public key and comment (encrypted), but not the actual private key. In general there are two ways to keep a private key protected by a device:

the simple way, just leave it stored on the device, and have the host store some kind of handle or identifier it can use to request the device use this particular key when needed for a privatekey operation (signature or decryption, but SSH client-auth uses only signature). Since hardware security devices, especially inexpensive ones, tend to have limited available memory, this may limit the number of application keys you can have (at least concurrently).

have the key 'wrapped' or 'sealed' by the device to a form that can be 'opened' only by the device, not externally. This is usually done by encrypting it under a master key that is kept only on the device; this allows essentially unlimited application keys to exist, protected by one device key -- or perhaps a handful of device keys for groups of application keys you need or want to manage differently. The host computer using the key (which to be clear in SSH terms is the client aka user) stores this wrapped value and passes it back to the device to be used for a needed privatekey operation.


(corrected) In FIDO2 these are called discoverable/resident and nondiscoverable/nonresident respectively and in either case are bound to a 'relying party identifier' which is supposed to be the remote website or server you are logging in to (to block phishing). According to https://docs.yubico.com/yesdk/users-manual/application-fido2/fido2-credentials.html Yubikey implements both; when I decrypt your posted example file, I find in the encrypted/privatekey section a single byte 01 followed by a 128-byte value that looks random, consistent with a wrapped (nonresident) key as @grawity_u1686 describes. SSH, including OpenSSH, doesn't bind a user key to a specific server in the protocol like FIDO2 (although you the user may of course choose to share and use a particular key only with a single server) so OpenSSH presumably uses some kind of generic 'relying party'.
Thus your device (Yubikey) is only needed to be inserted (and tapped if applicable) when you want OpenSSH to do a privatekey operation, which neither ssh-keygen -y or -e does. Making a connection using this keypair definitely does; adding it to an agent, with ssh-add for OpenSSH's agent or the equivalent for some other agent implementation, might do so: for a software key ssh-add does use the passphrase to decrypt it, and then there is no further protection, but I don't know how the hardware logic may differ.

In FIDO2 the private key isn't supposed to be stored on the device... traditional FIDO(U2F) had no storage on device; what the Yubico page doesn't mention is the "key handle" returned from device to relying party as part of the credential (and then sent back from RP to client when requesting an assertion) which is supposed to identify the key but really is a wrapped version of the full private key. In FIDO2 there is an option to have "resident" keys (which ssh-keygen has an option for; OP did not use it), but it is not the default. (And still problematic to use.)

@g: you're right, I didn't read far enough. Thanks.

Thank you, a very thorough explanation
